# Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window' Error while downloading Cropped Image

Tags: html, angular

I'm trying to save the cropped image. In Chrome when I do save as it downloads but fails while downloading from Download button which I added.

For cropping I used ngx-image-cropper. that works as intended.
I show the cropped image on screen and I want to download it but I am getting Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window' The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.

I tested the base64 string on online encoder decoder it is correctly codded.
I am  trying to do download as per below code

```
saveCroppedImage(): void {
      if (this.croppedImage) {
        // Extract base64 string
        const base64String = this.croppedImage.toString().split(',')[1];
        
        // Convert base64 string to Blob
        const blob = this.base64toBlob(base64String);
    
        // Create object URL for the Blob
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    
        // Create a link element
        const anchor = document.createElement('a');
        anchor.href = url;
        anchor.download = 'cropped_image.jpeg';
    
        // Trigger download
        anchor.click();
    
        // Clean up
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      }
    }
    
    private base64toBlob(base64String: string): Blob {
      const byteCharacters = atob(base64String);
      const byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
      for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
        byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
      }
      const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
      return new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
    }

    <div *ngIf="croppedImage">
    <button (click)="saveCroppedImage()">Download Image</button>
    </div>
```

**Attempt2**
based on solutions of other similar questions I tried using replace.

```
saveCroppedImage():void{
      if(this.croppedImage){
        const blob = this.base64toBlob(this.croppedImage);

        const anchor = document.createElement('a');
        anchor.href=  window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        anchor.download = 'cropped_image.jpeg'
        anchor.click();
      }
    }

    private base64toBlob(base6String: string):Blob {
      console.log("in blob",this.croppedImage);
      const base64EithoutPrefix =     base6String.toString().replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpeg|jpg);base64,/,'')
      const byteCharacters = atob(decodeURIComponent(base64EithoutPrefix));
      const byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
      for(let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++){
        
        byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);

      }
      const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
      return new Blob([byteArray],{type:'image/jpeg'});
    }
```

Yet still same issue haunts me.

Comment: Hey @Praful, if my answer below helps, then don't forget to mark it with a check so nobody else tries to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by taking below measures. I examined dataurl carefully I found there was one link getting added with single space after the encoded part maybe due to sanitized url.
Used one more split to remove it and problem was solved.

```
private base64toBlob(base64String: string):Blob {
     let base64WithoutPrefix = base64String.toString().split(',')[1];
     base64WithoutPrefix = base64WithoutPrefix.split(" ")[0];
     const byteCharacters = atob(base64WithoutPrefix);
     console.log(byteCharacters)
     const byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
     for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
       byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
     }
     const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
    
    
     return new Blob([byteArray], {type: 'image/png'});
   }

saveCroppedImage(): void {
      if (this.croppedImage) {
        const blob = this.base64toBlob(this.croppedImage);
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const anchor = document.createElement('a');
        anchor.href = url;
        anchor.download = 'cropped_image.jpeg';
        anchor.click();
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `this.croppedImage` isn't a **DataUrl** but a **BlobUrl** as *blob* output is the default behavior of ngx-image-cropper 7.0.  If it's not then I suggest changing it since you can use the BlobUrl directly without any conversions.

Changing to *blob* output makes *saveCroppedImage* a lot simpler, but you'll need to maintain an raw version of the URL and use that as your anchor's href value while maintaining a sanitized version for the cropped image if you are binding to it in an image element.

```
imageCropped(event: ImageCroppedEvent) {
  this.croppedImageRaw = event.objectUrl!;
  this.croppedImage = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.croppedImageRaw);
      
}
function saveCroppedImage(): void {
  const anchor = document.createElement('a');
  anchor.href = this.croppedImageRaw; // this is a string that begins with "blob:"
  anchor.download = 'cropped_image.jpeg';
  anchor.click();
}
```

Bonus:  Here's some code converting a BlobUrl to a DataUrl.  You don't need it, but I wrote before I realized you could use the blobUrl directly.

```
async function blobUrlToDataUrl(blobUrl: string) {
  const blob = await (await fetch(blobUrl)).blob();
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onerror = reject;
    fr.onload = () => resolve(fr.result);
    fr.readAsDataURL(blob);
  });
}
```

Comment: It's is DataUrl  with prefix like this data:image/[format]; base64

Comment: I updated my answer. If you can, stop using the DataUrl and use the BlobUrl instead since it'll make everything simpler.